# Error: Incorrect argument types for storage.StorageArea.set

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to store an array of objects using `storage.local`. When I try to call `set` to insert data to the storage, I get the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect argument types for storage.StorageArea.set.
```

Here is the manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
    "64": "icons/myicon.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/myicon.png",
    "default_title": "test",
    "default_popup": "popup/input.html"
  },

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["test.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "storage"
  ]

}
```

Here is the script:

```
browser.storage.local.set([{name:"Mog", eats:"mice"},{name:"Kraken", eats:"people"}]);
console.log(browser.storage.local.get());
```

There is lack of resources in webextension. So, sorry for the primitive question.

Comment: Note: `console.log(browser.storage.local.get());` is nonsensical. `storage.local.get()` is asynchronous. The data is only available in the callback (or `.then()`). See: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`storage.local.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set) is [expecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set#Parameters) a plain [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). While an Array is an Object, it has quite a bit more in its prototype than a plain Object. This is actually good to enforce, as permitting you to store a bare Array, could lead to confusion. For instance, what happens when you store a new array that is shorter? Should it remove all the entries which are not in the newly stored array, or leave them and have them returned when the data is retrieved?

To accomplish what you desire, you will just need to pick a name (key) under which to store your array. You could use something like:

```js
browser.storage.local.set({
    myArray: [{
        name: "Mog",
        eats: "mice"
    }, {
        name: "Kraken",
        eats: "people"
    }]
});
```

Comment: After I entered the data using your solution. I printed the storage using: `console.log(browser.storage.local.get());` but all what I get in the concole is: `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`.

Comment: @user6875880, As stated in my comment on your question, the code `console.log(browser.storage.local.get());` is nonsensical (i.e. it doesn't make sense; it won't work the way you're expecting). `storage.local.get()` is asynchronous. `browser.storage.local.get()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not the actual data. The data is only available in the callback (or .then(), for the `browser.*` Promise version of the API). See: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: I added an update. I hope it is clear. I look for a way to store objects in an array, or find a way to access objects by index because I do not always have the key values. e.g. when the user clicks on `edit` button, I identify the row by the button id, then, enable editing the row, then save it in that row's index in the storage. All what I have for the edit is that the user clicked edit in row number x.