# webextensions: How to get storage length and iterate over the objects

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to store objects in webextensions using local storage. A simple code is shown below (I have `title` and `content` as fixed string here, but I may need to get them as input).

After inserting an object to the local storage, I need to display it dynamically in an HTML page in the last row of the HTML table.

To do this, I need the table length (can be achieved) and the storage length (I could not achieve) to access the last object stored in the storage, get its values, insert them in the last row of the HTML table.

I faced two problems. Since I am not dealing with an array in the storage, I do not know how to get the length of the stored items and how to access the last added item and any item (i.e like accessing the array using the index number). I am re-writing and SDK code to webextension. So, I used to store items in the storage as an array of objects. I really could not do this in webextension and need your help. I prefer to re-write it with the minimal changes unless if I was doing something really wrong. What  Iwas doing is retrieving the last item in the storage and create new row in the HTML table and add it and I get the item stored in the storage and displayed in the HTML table.

In the console, when I log the `rows` in the console, I just see the word `object`. How to access the objects one-by-one to get their properties to display them in the HTML page?

Can you clarify please?

1) `index.js`

```
function insertRow()
{
  var title = "XYZ" //I'm using fixed value but this is can be multiple objects read from the user whenever he inserts a new objects.
  var content = "X";
  storeRow(title,content);
}//end insertRow

    //---------------------------------------------
function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}
//----------------------------------------------
function onGot(rows){
  console.log("onGot: "+rows.length); //row.length - does not work
}
//-------------------------------------
function storeRow(title,content)
{
  var rows = {}; //define object
  rows.title = title;
  rows.content = content;

  var storingRow = browser.storage.local.set(rows); //insert the object to the storage.
  console.log("row inserted");
  storingRow.then(() => {
  displayRow(rows);
  }, onError);
}//end storeRow
//--------------------------------------

function displayRow(rows)
{
  let gettingItem = browser.storage.local.get();
  gettingItem.then(onGot, onError);
}//end displayRow
```

2) `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",

"background": {
    "scripts": ["index.js"]
  },

    "permissions":[
        "activeTab",
        "storage"
    ],

}
```

**UPDATE:**
To be specific, in SDK, I used to do this to define a storage array:

```
if(!info.storage.myStorage) 
{
    info.storage.myStorage = []; //declare a new storage. 
}//end if
```

Then, push the objects on it.
var myObject = {}; //define object.

```
myObject.title = "cccc";
myObject.content="zzzz";
info.storage.myStorage.push(myObject);
```

Then, I can `edit`, `update`, and `delete` storage items from the HTML page based on the `row id`. The idea is, after the item is stored in the storage, it is displayed in the HTML page. I have links in each row for `edit` for example, and when the user clicks on it, I identify the storage array `index` from the `id` of the `edit` button (numbered by the row). But, in webextensions, I do not have array, and when the user clicks `edit`, I need to identify the storage element by the `row` number. Do you have any idea how to do this? and if no way, what is the alternative?

Comment: What you are doing looks like you are overwriting the same data `title` and `content` every time you are storing a row. Why is it such a problem to just pick a key name, which you use in `storage.local` to store your array as an array? If it is that you want it to be stored every time you `.push()` or `pop()`, etc., then just define functions to do so or create a new Object which does that when you call those methods.

Comment: You mean a key for each object? I can't choose a key because the `title` and `content` are read from a form and taken as input from the user. I do not enter these values manually as in this simple example. So how can assign automatic key each time the user input values? What I want is that the user can input any number of `title` and `content`. The, I want to edit, delete, update these values. The edit, delete and update are buttons and has click events. When they are clicked, I need to refer to the row/index or key in the storage that corresponds to them.

Comment: All what I have when edit, delete or update buttons are clicked is the row index (taken from the id of the button), then I refer to the storage from it and update or delete. I could not do this without array. Or, I need more clarification and example on how this can be done without an array.

Comment: `Why is it such a problem to just pick a key name, which you use in storage.local to store your array as an array?` can you explain with the code? I do not get whether you mean key name for each object? or for all objects? if for each object, how to make it automatically assigned? If you look at the update in my post please to see what I used to do. This is what I need to do now.

Comment: I'm happy to do so, but the code is basically the same as I used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44509621/3773011) to your earlier question. In that answer, I use the key `myArray` to store an array of Objects, which appears to be what you desire. It is stored as an Array and retrieved as an Array, which is what I understand you want. Obviously, each Object in the array can have arbitrary key/value pairs (as long as they remain JSON-ifiable (e.g. no circular references; no DOM elements; no functions, etc.)). If you are wanting something other than that, please explain further.

Comment: @Makyen I seem getting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store an array in local storage instead of each row, and then store each row in the array stored in local storage.

```
browser.storage.local.get("rows")
.then((rows =>
{
  var row = {};
  row.title = title;
  row.content = content;
  rows.push(row);

  return browser.storage.local.set("rows", rows);
}))
.then(() => console.log("row inserted"))
.then(() => browser.storage.local.get("rows"))
.then(displayRows);
```